# change different columns using colClasses in a single attempt in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset in csv as follows-

[image]

Sample of the data is as well pasted below

Now I have columns like Transaction.Data which is Date type but read.csv is expecting real , again Transaction is String, which I want to convert to Dr.(0) and Cr.(1) , and I have Amount which has comma in-between, which I want to change to Integer or vector with decimal so that I could plot.

To convert Cr.(1) and Dr.(0) , I found the solution from my previous question as-'

```
setClass("CrDr")
setAs("character", "CrDr", function(from) c(Cr.=1,Dr.=0)[from])
```

So now I have 3 things to do while reading the csv-

1. Transaction.data <- date
2. Transaction <- Dr.(0) Cr.(1)
3. Amount/Balance <- numeric

How to achieve these many kind of changes in a single attempt.

**Data Sample**

```
Transaction Date    Remarks Transaction Amount  Balance
26/05/2014  ATM/CASH WDL/26-05-14/18:12:12/0    Dr. 3,000.00    1,11,216.17
26/05/2014  ATD/Auto Debit CC5xx3009    Dr. 3,953.22    1,14,216.17
22/05/2014  TRFR FROM:SRI GANESH INFRATECH &SOFTWARE PVT LTD    Cr. 36,000.00   1,18,169.39
21/05/2014  BIL/000593351901/priyanka/VODAESP_MICI335   Dr. 555 82,169.39
17/05/2014  IPS/SPENCERS RE/20140517124555/0    Dr. 514 82,724.39
12/5/2014   BIL/000589207330/Kolkataairfare/INDIGO_MICI3346 Dr. 7,617.00    83,238.39
6/5/2014    BIL/000586940549/Mumma#May/NSP  Dr. 1,10,000.00 90,855.39
3/5/2014    BIL/000585385115/airtel#bb/AIRTEL_MICI3338  Dr. 797 2,00,855.39
3/5/2014    IPS/SPENCERS RE/20140503112817/0    Dr. 328 2,01,652.39
1/5/2014    NEFT-AXMB141215740194-ABHISHEK CHOUDHARY-may month  Cr. 1,00,000.00 2,01,980.39
29/04/2014  TRFR FROM:SRI GANESH INFRATECH & SOFTWARE PVT LTD   Cr. 12,000.00   1,01,980.39
26/04/2014  ATM/CASH WDL/26-04-14/21:20:31/0    Dr. 1,000.00    89,980.39
25/04/2014  ATD/Auto Debit CC5xx3009    Dr. 897 90,980.39
19/04/2014  VIN/Tata_Sky_DT/20140419180921/0    Dr. 351 91,877.39
10/4/2014   BY CASH  - BHOPAL   Cr. 3,000.00    92,228.39
31/03/2014  BIL/000570396248/Mumma#Mar/NSP  Dr. 1,50,000.00 89,228.39
31/03/2014  NEFT-AXMB140902244145-ABHISHEK CHOUDHARY-   Cr. 30,000.00   2,39,228.39
```

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but please don't post images of data. If you can copy and paste an image, you can copy and paste the text so that we can actually use it to experiment for answers.

Comment: @thelatemail accepted my mistake, added the actual dataset